# How can I prevent nginx from serving http/2?

Tags: nginx, debian, http2

I am working on implementing http/2 for an ecommerce website my company made. I'm hosting it on debian jessie and found that it's now pretty easy to get nginx from the backports repo which was built against openssl 1.0.2 to support ALPN (which is necessary these days to work with chrome).

So I upgraded my libssl and then my nginx. To my great surprise, nginx now seems to be serving my content through http2 even though I didn't add that keyword to the config. Chrome's dev tools show `h2` in the `protocol` column of the network tab.

Normally I would be happy about that, but I'd like to make some comparison measurements between http1.1 and http2. How can I force it to serve http1.1 again (temporarily) to make my measurements?

Edit: adding output of `nginx -V` to be specific about my version

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.9.10
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads --add-module=/build/nginx-1.9.10/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-1.9.10/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/nginx-1.9.10/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/nginx-1.9.10/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/nginx-1.9.10/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Comment: If you're proxying, have you tried the `proxy_http_version 1.1;` directive?

Comment: I am proxying: my first nginx terminates TLS, then it goes to Varnish and then another nginx which has the real application config. Are you suggesting to add this directive to the first nginx?

Comment: Yip, that's the suggestion.

Comment: I doubt Varnish would upgrade the http version unless explicitly specified in your Varnish config.

Comment: I have added the line to the `location` block and reloaded nginx, but nothing changed from what I can see.

Comment: Strange... Have you flushed the cache? If all else fails, try adding it to the other Nginx config, although I suspect that this won't have any effect.

Comment: flushed which cache?

Comment: Apologies, that was a silly comment. It seems as if others have experienced similar oddities, but nobody has a solution yet.

Comment: I just wish you had the  `--disable-http-2` option from [my favourite web server](https://www.shimmercat.com/en/docs/1.5/command-line-reference/)

Comment: Which version of nginx is it? I can't reproduce with 1.11.3. Does `/usr/sbin/nginx -T | grep http2` show any hits, by any chance?

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt I have added version details to the question. I indeed have the `http2` directive in two site configurations (`server{}` blocks), but those sites are different from the one I'm talking about here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation:](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)

> The http2 parameter (1.9.5) configures the port to accept HTTP/2 connections.

Thus any virtual server configured on this port will accept HTTP/2 connections. If you want to configure some hosts with HTTP/2 but other without, then you have to use different IP or ports.

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize the meaning of that. So since all my servers listen on port 443 it's either all or none for http2.